# TypeScript doesn't understand "import" from library in Node.js. Get SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, ts-node

I'm using the [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid) library in Node.js, but I'm writing my backend in TypeScript.

When I try to compile my TypeScript, I get:

```js
/project/node_modules/nanoid/async/index.js:1
import crypto from 'crypto'
       ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/project/dist/utils/generateId.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
```

This is the piece of code that causes it:

```js
import { customAlphabet } from "nanoid/async";
```

I figured it would just naturally work?

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

My node version is `v12.10.0` and my typescript version is `v3.7.4`.

Comment: It looks like the package of nanoid is written in esm style which needs to be converted to cjs

Comment: @tmhao2005 I think I need something like this, https://github.com/standard-things/esm, right?

Comment: I used your `tsconfig.json` and tried the `customAlphabet` import and it looks fine - https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-chebyshev-dr6qo. May be post a bit more of your code or create a sandbox

Comment: @ultimoTG I don't think codesandbox adds much clarity, as this'll work with web bundlers - it's specifically a node-related issue. Nonetheless, I have come up with a solution for now that I'll post.

Comment: I have no idea why you run cjs code which can import an esm module in that. It looks like  `nanoid` has a very clear definition `module`/`main` properties for (esm and cjs respectively) in their package.json file

Comment: @tmhao2005 I really don't know why my project isn't going for the cjs-specific file. I feel like that would automatically work. No other library gives me these issues.

Comment: Do you have a sample repo for this issue?

Comment: I’m not sure if you update the latest node version it would work? Will you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that line be either
`import { crypto } from 'crypto'`
or
`import * as crypto from 'crypto'`
?

Comment: Not sure it matters as the issue is the import. Also, even if it was an issue, then that's just a library issue seeing as this error is happening within my node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

try this `import * as crypto from 'crypto'`